# Delegate/forward Kerberos tickets with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, kerberos

I'm trying to find information whether the Spring Security implementation of Kerberos handles delegation/forwarding of ticket granting tickets so that my app server can call other Kerberos services reusing the principals TGT? Any documentation on this would be highly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring security does not implement any Kerberos functionality. If you are referring to the kerberos **[extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/index.html)** then the answer is no. It only does authentication and it's just a wrapper around the Java JAAS API [`Krb5LoginModule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is possible since the release of [Spring Security Kerberos](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/) 1.0.0.

The `SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator` can be configured to store the authentication context:

```
ticketValidator.setHoldOnToGSSContext(true);
```

Here's some code to get you started:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if (authentication instanceof KerberosServiceRequestToken) {
    KerberosServiceRequestToken token = (KerberosServiceRequestToken) authentication;

    if (token.getTicketValidation() == null) {
        // No delegation possible...
    } else {
        GSSContext context = token.getTicketValidation().getGssContext();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator has isInitiator flag set to false. This causes context.getCredDeleg() to return false.
I have done a POC where my observation is the delegation/forward works only if isInitiator is set to true.
Any hints related to this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As Koraktor mentioned, SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator class has the details which are equivalent to the JAAS config file. However, `SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator` has `isInitiator` flag set to false. This causes `context.getCredDeleg()` to return false, and you can not delegate the credentials.
I have done a POC where my observation is the delegation/forward works only if `isInitiator` is set to true.

I solved this issue by writing my own `TicketValidator`, everything from `SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator` kept as it is, except, changed the entry of isInitiator flag to  `options.put("isInitiator", "true");`

Comment: Do you some sample code about the ticketvalidator?

Comment: don't have the code of TicketValidator at the moment. https://github.com/bhushan1987/SAMLAndKerberos/blob/master/src/main/java/kerberos/KerberosTest.java this is done without using spring, using pure java. Spring has exact same code internally